# "This application is not responding" nonsense with X11 forwarding

Tags: x11, gnome, xforwarding

I have a server running XFCE on debian and a client running gnome3 on arch, and I want to control GUI applications running on server from client using X11 forwarding.

`ssh -X user@server` on the client followed by `localc` - Works!

Except every few seconds no matter what I do - even moving the window - gnome tells me "Libreoffice Calc is not responding. Do you want to force quit it?". This happens with the calculator too, anything.

Yeah I admit there is a slight lag (a guessed 0.3 seconds - Can this be improved somehow?) but it's definitely not unresponsive. The dialog comes up every few seconds. Nothing's frozen or anything.

Edit: Setting `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 20000` still shows the dialog, just now only every 20 seconds even though nothing is unresponsive at all. Setting it to `0` to disbale it worked, but I'd sure like to find and fix the real issue causing gnome to think it's unresponsive when it isn't.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, what am I missing?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 0` that's the user-friendliness GNOME is famous for :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On 3.36 or newer you can use this command to disable the check: `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 0`. Or you can try something longer than the default timeout of 5000 milliseconds instead of 0 if you don't want to disable it entirely.

Comment: I've tried setting this to 10s and 20s - In both cases I get the same results (just after 10/20 seconds). This is really weird, I think the issue is elsewhere. Setting it to 0 works even though finding the real issue (as I'm sure this can't be normal since nothing is ever unresponsive) would be nice. Until then I accept this answer since it did fix my problem.

Comment: Can this discussion be reopen / restarted >>?? I am having same issue and like to find out where is the source of this and obviously  fix it . If it is an OS issue that is ad iffernt strory...

Comment: Can this discussion be reopen / restarted >>?? I am having same issue and like to find out where is the source of this problem and obviously  fix it . If it is an OS issue that is a different story...and I would prefer NOT to get into OS issues, such as "try this XYZ OS -  it works for me... I need a solution for my current OS.

Comment: @anne add new question with details of Your OS. As You tried answer from there and it won't help - refer it in question.